# How to know if a spinor $\Psi\left(x\right)$ is the ground state of the system?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics, schroedinger-equation, variational-principle, spinors

Suppose we have time independent one-dimensional single particle Schrödinger-like equation$$-\frac{d}{dx}\left(A\left(x\right)\frac{d}{dx}\psi\left(x\right)\right)+V\left(x\right)\psi\left(x\right)=E\psi\left(x\right),$$
where $A\left(x\right)$ is a positive function. We have guessed an eigenfunction $\psi_{\mathrm{guess}}\left(x\right)$ of energy $E_{\mathrm{guess}}$, and wonder if this is the ground state of the system.

I know two methods we can use in order to check if $\psi_{\mathrm{guess}}\left(x\right)$ is the ground state of the system:

1. If $\psi_{\mathrm{guess}}\left(x\right)$ has no nodes, than it is the ground state.
2. If we can write the Hamiltonian in the form of $H=E_0 + \varepsilon a^{\dagger}a$, and $E_{\mathrm{guess}}$ happens to be equal to $E_0$, than $\psi_{\mathrm{guess}}\left(x\right)$ is the ground state.

My question is about a spinor analog of this. Suppose we have time independent one-dimensional Schrödinger equation for spin $s$ particle$$-\frac{d}{dx}\left(A\left(x\right)\frac{d}{dx}\Psi\left(x\right)\right)+V\left(x\right)\Psi\left(x\right)=E\Psi\left(x\right),$$
where $A\left(x\right)$ is a positive-defined $(2s+1)\times (2s+1)$ hermitian matrix, and $V\left(x\right)$ is a $(2s+1)\times (2s+1)$ hermitian matrix. We again guessed an eigenspinor $\Psi_{\mathrm{guess}}\left(x\right)$ of energy $E_{\mathrm{guess}}$, and wonder if this is the ground state of the system.

Method $(2)$ I metioned above should still work, but looks like it is mostly impracticle. Is there a generaliztion of method $(1)$, or of some other method, that can help solving the problem?

Comment: You mean *s*-dimensional spinor, not spin *s*. You could try inserting parameters in your wave function, and see if the energy expectation value for the variational test functions is concave w.r.t. all parameters at your state.

Comment: You don't guess eigenfunctions. You need to solve an equation.

Comment: @Cosmas Zachos Thanks for the correction and the suggestion. The problem is that I think that this method won't prove that $\Psi_{\mathrm{guess}}$ is the ground state if it is one, it would just show that this is the lowest energy within the family I checked.

Comment: Correct. Not  a proof.

Comment: If it is a spinor, how can you write down a position space wavefunction $\psi(x)$? Also, I think that a position dependent potential $V(x)$ will never affect the dynamics of a spinor.

Comment: @my2cts Sometimes we don't have methods to solve an equation. Guessing the answer is also a way to solve.

Comment: @abir A particle with non-zero spin described by a position dependant spinor. The position dependent potential $V(x)$ does affect the dynamics of the spinor. For example, see [Pauli equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_equation).

Comment: @roy This equation is peanuts. Why don't you just solve it?

Comment: @my2cts What do you mean? There is no general solution to Schrödinger equation, let alone to the spinor one.

Comment: @roy There are methods to solve equations. Guessing is an act of desperation.